# How can you Sort a stream by timestamp in Reactivex?

Tags: rxjs, reactivex, rxdart

I've combined streams from firestore and now I need to sort them by timestamp (descending) . I really don't know much about reactiveX ...I'm using dartRx. I seen a few solutions using a comparator but not really sure how to use it.

```
Class Order{
Timestamp timestamp;
}

Stream<List<Order>> sortByTimestamp(){
return combineList(order).....//my stream
}
```

Comment: In RxJS you can sort a stream only after it completes. In other words, you need to complete the observable, collect the values emitted in an array maybe using the `toArray` operator and then use the `sort` method of Array to sort. If the firestore stream does not complete, than you need to check whether it is possible to do the sorting within firestore itself.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your question.
Here is my way :)

```
return combineList(order).map((orders) => orders.sort(comparator).toList());
```